# Levi decomposition and minimal parabolics

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let G be  reductive group over a field $k$. Let $P_0$ be a minimal k-parabolic subgroup of G and fix a Levi decomposition $P_0=M_0 N_0$. If P is a parabolic containing $P_0$, then why is there only one Levi subgroup M of P such that $P=MN$ where $M$ contains $M_0$?

Comment: By minimality, $M_0 = Z_G(S)$ for a maximal split $k$-torus $S \subset P_0$. Let $T \supset S$ be a maximal $k$-torus in $M_0$, so it is maximal in $G$ and hence in $P$. Thus, $T$ is contained in a *unique* Levi $k$-subgroup $M$ of $P$ (see Proposition 12.3.1 in https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110663) and $T\subset Z_G(S)$, so it suffices that $M\supset Z_G(S)$. Since $M=Z_G(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda:{\rm{GL}}_1\to G$, we have $M\supset Z_G(S')$ for a maximal split $k$-torus $S'\subset M$ containing $\lambda({\rm{GL}}_1)$. But $S$ and $S'$ are $M(k)$-conjugate.